# Successful delete message is not being called

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

After deleting the row in the gridview, i wish to fire an alert message saying that "Record was successfully deleted"

I have written the following code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' >function demoalert() {");
sb.Append(@"alert('Hello!demo!');");
sb.Append("} </script>");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Delete", sb.ToString());
```

and after this code, i am binding my grid with datasource and updating the update panel. The alert doesn't fire up.

Script debugging is not disabled in my IE (IE-8)

Please guide!

Comment: See @James Hill's answer - you're never calling the method you're writing, unless of course there's more code to be posted... in which case, post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the `demoalert()` function after writing it to the page? Unless we're missing code, it appears that you're not calling the function.

If that's the case, simply change your last Append to:

```
sb.Append("} demoalert(); </script>");
```

Alternatively, you could remove the function altogether:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
sb.Append(@"alert('Hello!demo!');");
sb.Append("</script>");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Delete", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: @Xorpower, what about it is not working? Are you getting a JavaScript error? Is the solution not compiling?

Comment: @XorPower, We're going to need some more information if you'd like us to help. Saying that "nothing" is working isn't enough information to come up with a fix. Are you registering the script block in the `onload` event of the page? Have you looked at the JS console to see if any error are being thrown? Help us help you :)

Comment: I am not registering script block in the onload Page. I am registering after the row gets deleted in row deleting event

Answer (score 1):

Skip the function and try

```
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' >");
    sb.Append(@"alert('Hello!demo!');");
    sb.Append("</script>");

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Delete", sb.ToString());
```

or simply

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                        "Delete", "alert('Hello!demo!');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RecordDeletedMessage", sb.ToString());
```